# Reddit only partially working in Ubuntu

Tags: browser

I was able to use Reddit a week or so ago. For the past few days I've been able to log in ( I think but it's hard to be certain ) in Ubuntu but not much else. Most of the posts are missing, my profile etc. isn't loading and I can't post comments. It appears that I can make new posts but they don't appear. I'm not 'shadowbanned' because everything's fine in Windows 7 and on my Android phone. I've tried Chrome and Firefox. Any ideas, please ? Thank you.

Comment: [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1312993/edit) to mention which browser you are using.

Comment: Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: This could be problem with your network. I never encounter this before. Could you add console/F12 message?